# Any way to compare/match sentences with only a different word order?

Tags: mysql, function, compare

I have 2 MySQL tables , each with address data of companies in it. One table is more recent, but has no telephone and no website data. Now I want to unite these tables into 1 recent *and* complete table.

But for some companies the order of the words is different,like this:

`'Bakery Johnson'` in table 1 and `'Johnson Bakery'` in table 2.

Now I need to find a way to compare these values, as they're obviously the same company.

I think I will somehow have to split those names first, and then order the different parts alphabetically.

Any chance anybody has done something like this before, and willing to share some code or function?

***UPDATE:***
I found a function that sorts words inside a string. I can use this to detect name swaps as described above. It's quite SLOW though...

See :  [MySQL: how to sort the words in a string using a stored function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939936/mysql-how-to-sort-the-words-in-a-string-using-a-stored-function)

Comment: "they're obviously the same company" I disagree. So does the law in every country that I've ever heard of.

Comment: well, these values come from 2 different yellow-pages like sources, and there are differences like these between them...Some guides prefer to use a different name for easier sorting, I guess...

Comment: That's highly ambiguous. What defines whether these two strings _actually_ represent the same entity? I'd want to perform some analysis on the presentation semantics of each data source, before leaping to a requirement like this.

Comment: I also compare on postalcode. One table has no telephone no's, otherwise that would be the best way to compare of course... I think the margin of error is quite low when comparing postalcodes as well

Answer (score 1):

If your table is `MyISAM` you can run this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+bakery +johnson')
```

This will find all records containing the words `bakery` and `johnson` (and probably some other words too).

Creating a `FULLTEXT` index on the table:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX
        fx_mytable_name
ON      mytable (name)
```

will speed up this query.

Comment: Thanks, they're InnoDB, but I could convert...  there's no fulltext searching in InnoDB ?

Comment: "Not The Johnson Bakery At All" oops

Comment: @Tomalak: *and probably some other words too*

Comment: I admit it's kind of dangerous. But I can also check if they're the same length (while removing spaces,etc.)

Comment: @Dylan: no, `MATCH` does not work in `InnoDB`. It works in `MyISAM` even without a `FULLTEXT` index.

Answer (score 0):

Going back a bit on your solution, you could go with a similar way as modern phones resolve duplicate names conflicts

You present your user with the option, as he finds something suspicious:

`Is this a duplicate? Use our [ Merge ] option`

**You are merging Bakery Johnson, please select the source/original item:**

`[ Johnson Bakery v ]` (my amazing dropdown!)

Everything not already in Johnson Bakery gets ported to Bakery Johnson (orders for example), you may also show an intermediate screen displaying what will be merged, or let the user pick, for example, he wants the address info from Johnson Bakery and orders from both etc

It is not self correcting as you asked, but the collaboration from the users may be more accurate than AI here. I also love low-tech solutions like this so let us know what you ended up doing.