# Search column for a string in every space separated value

Tags: php, mysql, string, search

Suppose I have a column named CustomerNames in database with values:

1. Vins et **al**cools Chevalier
2. Magazzini **Al**imentari Riuniti
3. Hungry Owl **Al**l-Night Grocers
4. Split Rail Beer & **Al**e
5. **Al**freds Futterkiste

I want to make a query which will search only for the first letters of FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME, and list the names in ASC order based on FIRSTNAME then LASTNAME.
for example if I search for "al" in above table, it should return me something like below:

1. **Al**freds Futterkiste
2. Vins et **al**cools Chevalier
3. Split Rail Beer & **Al**e
4. Magazzini **Al**imentari Riuniti
5. Hungry Owl **Al**l-Night Grocers

I have used below query.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerName LIKE 'al%' OR CustomerName LIKE '% al%' ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Output:

1. **Al**freds Futterkiste
2. Hungry Owl **Al**l-Night Grocers
3. Magazzini **Al**imentari Riuniti
4. Split Rail Beer & **Al**e
5. Vins et **al**cools Chevalier

Which is ordering results only on the basis of firstnames.
But I want a query which gives output using firstnames and then lastnames.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you can differentiate first name and last name if they are all in one column ...

Comment: you do not need to differentiate it by giving them any name, lets say these values are space separated values and I want to give priority to first word (before occurrence of first space ) then next and then to following

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's a straight forward answer to that. You need to write a function or store procedure to order results based on a column-values-that-is-space-separated

Have a look at this
[MySQL: how to sort the words in a string using a stored function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939936/mysql-how-to-sort-the-words-in-a-string-using-a-stored-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
where CustomerName LIKE 'al%' 
OR CustomerName LIKE '% al%' 
ORDER BY substring(CustomerName, instr(CustomerName, 'al'))
```

Comment: instr supported from MySQL Version : 5.6

Comment: ok, so it worked but does not give required results. i.e 1.)Vins et alcools Chevalier
2.)Split Rail Beer & Ale
3.)Alfreds Futterkiste
4.)Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti
5.)Hungry Owl All-Night Grocers